# How to use angular data binding within a rails helper declaration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I work on an angular app that is tightly integrated with rails. I want to use a rails time zone select helper to populate a select dropdown with all timezones, as well as set the default selected option to be the timezone of the selected user.

Here is what the rails helper example is:

```
time_zone_select( "user", "time_zone", nil, default: "Pacific Time (US & Canada)" )
```

I want to use a data binding within the rails helper declaration to set the current user's timezone as being initially selected.

```
time_zone_select( "user", "time_zone", nil, default: "{{selectedUser.timezone}}" )
```

Would this work? Is there an 'angular way' to populate a timezone select?

Thanks!

Comment: should be easy to find timezones in json format  to pass into angular `ng-options`

Comment: in my experience that won't work, use ng-options instead.

Comment: @charlietfl im gonna give this a try today. It seems like a solution.